# Does the Raspberry pi 4 have USB 3.0 or 3.1?

Tags: usb, data-transfer

I've seen many, varying reports on the natives USB ports on the Raspberry Pi. Some say that the Pi has 3.0 ports, while others say that the pi has 3.1 ports.

In many applications, the distinction is critical, as USB 3.1 doubles the transfer rate of 3.0.

What type of USB interface does the raspberry Pi 4 support, and does the Compute module 4 support the same interface?

Comment: Have you tried the RPF product pages? https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/raspberry-pi-4-model-b/specifications/?resellerType=home

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's something that can be answered by reading the official RPF/RPTL documentation and therefore a complete waste of time.

Comment: @Dougie the RPF is self conflicting, and I think that because of that, reading it is a complete waste of time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Raspberry Pi 4 supports only USB 2.0 (2 ports) and USB 3.0 (2 ports). All other RPis support only USB 2.0. RPi 4 does not support the higher speeds of USB 3.1. This is due to their hardware implementation - the SoC (BCM 2711) simply does not have the capability to support higher speeds. The Compute module uses the same SoC, and has the same constraint.